# Conceptualizing a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Sorry for the vague title.

So let's say we have a set $\mathbb R ^2$ that has $+$ and $*$ as laws, how can I show that it is/isn't a $\mathbb R$-vector space if:

$(x,y) + (x', y') = (y+y', x+x') \\
a*(x,y) = (ax,ay)$

What actually is a $\mathbb R$-vector space? Am I actually trying to prove that this is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, since we already know that $\mathbb R^2$ is a vector space? Or am I just supposed to go down the list of criteria and check all the requirements?

Truth be told, I'm not totally sure how to interpret this question, and I'm not sure how to conceptualize a vector space. Is it just a space where, if the set fulfills are the requirements, I can stuff vectors into? How would you explain it to a linear algebra newbie? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What actually is a R-vector space? Am I actually trying to prove that this is a subspace of R2, since we already know that R2 is a vector space? Or am I just supposed to go down the list of criteria and check all the requirements?"

I'm assuming it's the second one, because the set you're looking at is exactly $\mathbb R^2$ with its usual operations.

Each individual requirement shouldn't be too hard. For instance, addition is associative because

$
(x, y) + [(x', y') + (x'', y'')] = (x, y) + (x' + x'', y' + y'')
$

$
= (x + (x' + x''), y + (y' + y'')) 
$

$
= ((x + x') + x'', (y + y') + y'') 
$

$
= [(x, y) + (x', y')] + (x'', y'').
$

so that the property is true basically because it's true for real numbers so that the equality in the middle happens. All the rest of them will be basically the same.

As far as how you should conceptualize them, the typical way of thinking of $\mathbb R^2$ is as arrows in the plane. The way of thinking of other vectors space is, honestly, that they all look kind of like $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$. There are theorems you'll learn that will teach you that all vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ "look like" $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how does the visualization of the vector space change based on the operations used? Does it change at all?

Comment: In some sense the same visualization still holds. If you had different operations, but still found that the result was a vector space then it will turn out that the result is "isomorphic" to some $\mathbb R^n$, so that there's some way to identify it with the normal version of $\mathbb R^n$. I think most people just think of all vector spaces (over $\mathbb R$) as somehow looking like $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: So for example, one axiom is that the vector space has to be commutative. That means that I have to show that the two operations in the problem I showed about are commutative? I'm just supposed to take any axiom for addition and check if it works with the first operation, and take every axiom for multiplication and see if it works with the second operation (on $\mathbb R^2$), right?

Comment: "all vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ "look like" $\mathbb R^n$". All **finite-dimensional** ones you should say...

Comment: Yes, that's an important correction Gabriel Romon. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, user494405, that's basically what you have to do. Vector spaces are defined as sets with two operations satisfying your list of conditions. So the process of proving something is a vector space usually amounts to just going down the checklist. It's usually not the most exciting thing ever, but it's also usually not that hard. Just write out what it means for an operation to be commutative and check that that is true for your operations.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of a vector space is an *algebraic abstraction* of the familiar geometric vectors on the plane, or in the 3d space. 
Namely (in the first round) we keep only the facts that:

- two vectors can be added
- a vector can be multiplied by a *real* number

and we write up the essential properties of these operations, which make them analogous to 'addition' and 'multipliciation-by-scalar'. 
In contrast, for a $\Bbb Q$-vector space it's only required that vectors can be multiplied by *rational* numbers.

This generalization turns out to work well enough together with intuitions, e.g. we can specify the *dimension* of any vector space, and we can introduce *coordinates*, etc.

As to your specific questions, yes, in an exercise like this you just have to check that the axioms for addition and multiplication-by-scalar are satisfied. 
Note that the given operations on $\Bbb R^2$ are just the natural operations, and yes, it is a vector space.